# Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect in JAMOD

Tags: java, master-slave, modbus

JAMOD API for MODBUS is used for creating Master and Slave.Slave is started fine but Master is throwing error as Connection refused.I followed the code given in
below urls
http://jamod.sourceforge.net/kb/tcp_master_howto.html
http://jamod.sourceforge.net/kb/tcp_slave_howto.html

Please help me to find what's wrong with code

**Exception :**

```
Hello ...........ModbusMaster1
localhost:5555:0:4:3
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at net.wimpi.modbus.net.TCPMasterConnection.connect(TCPMasterConnection.java:65)
    at jamod.test.master.ModbusMaster1.main(ModbusMaster1.java:54)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

**Master Program:**

```
package jamod.test.master;

import java.net.InetAddress;

import net.wimpi.modbus.Modbus;
import net.wimpi.modbus.io.ModbusTCPTransaction;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputDiscretesRequest;
import net.wimpi.modbus.msg.ReadInputDiscretesResponse;
import net.wimpi.modbus.net.TCPMasterConnection;

public class ModbusMaster1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello ...........ModbusMaster1");
        /* The important instances of the classes mentioned before */
        TCPMasterConnection con = null; //the connection
        ModbusTCPTransaction trans = null; //the transaction
        ReadInputDiscretesRequest req = null; //the request
        ReadInputDiscretesResponse res = null; //the response

        /* Variables for storing the parameters */
        InetAddress addr = null; //the slave's address
        int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;
        int ref = 0; //the reference; offset where to start reading from
        int count = 0; //the number of DI's to read
        int repeat = 1; //a loop for repeating the transaction

        String inputs[] = {"localhost:5555","0","4","3"};

        if (inputs.length < 3) {
              System.exit(1);
            } else {
              try {
                String astr = inputs[0];
                int idx = astr.indexOf(':');
                if(idx > 0) {
                  port = Integer.parseInt(astr.substring(idx+1));
                  astr = astr.substring(0,idx);
                }
                addr = InetAddress.getByName(astr);
                ref = Integer.decode(inputs[1]).intValue();
                count = Integer.decode(inputs[2]).intValue();
                if (inputs.length == 4) {
                  repeat = Integer.parseInt(inputs[3]);
                }
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
              }
            }
        System.out.println(inputs[0]+":"+inputs[1]+":"+inputs[2]+":"+inputs[3]);
        //2. Open the connection
        con = new TCPMasterConnection(addr);
        con.setPort(port);
        con.connect();

        //3. Prepare the request
        req = new ReadInputDiscretesRequest(ref, count);

        //4. Prepare the transaction
        trans = new ModbusTCPTransaction(con);
        trans.setRequest(req);

        //5. Execute the transaction repeat times
        int k = 0;
        do {
          trans.execute();
          res = (ReadInputDiscretesResponse) trans.getResponse();
          System.out.println("Digital Inputs Status=" + res.getDiscretes().toString());
          k++;
        } while (k < repeat);

         //6. Close the connection
         con.close();
    }
}
```

**Slave Program :**

```
package jamod.test.slave;

import net.wimpi.modbus.Modbus;
import net.wimpi.modbus.ModbusCoupler;
import net.wimpi.modbus.net.ModbusTCPListener;
import net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.SimpleDigitalIn;
import net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.SimpleDigitalOut;
import net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.SimpleInputRegister;
import net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.SimpleProcessImage;
import net.wimpi.modbus.procimg.SimpleRegister;

public class ModbusSlave1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello ...........ModbusSlave1");
        ModbusTCPListener listener = null;
        SimpleProcessImage spi = null;
        int port = Modbus.DEFAULT_PORT;

        // 1. Set port number from parameter

            port = 5555;



        // 2. Prepare a process image
        spi = new SimpleProcessImage();
        spi.addDigitalOut(new SimpleDigitalOut(true));
        spi.addDigitalOut(new SimpleDigitalOut(false));
        spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(false));
        spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(true));
        spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(false));
        spi.addDigitalIn(new SimpleDigitalIn(true));
        spi.addRegister(new SimpleRegister(251));
        spi.addInputRegister(new SimpleInputRegister(45));

        // 3. Set the image on the coupler
        ModbusCoupler.getReference().setProcessImage(spi);
        ModbusCoupler.getReference().setMaster(false);
        ModbusCoupler.getReference().setUnitID(15);

        // 4. Create a listener with 3 threads in pool
        listener = new ModbusTCPListener(3);
        listener.setPort(port);
        listener.start();
    }
}
```